# Asking for critiques: On- or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

When I was working on a comment [on this question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3137/9), I was trying to think of a way for the question to be edited and able to be on-topic. Since the asker was asking how to view the bids that had won, my assumption is that the asker's end goal is to improve their bids and have a better chance at winning future projects.

Would it be considered on-topic to ask for bid critiques ("What's wrong with my bid?"), or would those sorts of questions be considered too broad?

Answer (score 2):

I see it as a website support question, and should be closed... Currently

Comment: Right, it's currently off-topic as is. My question had been more of whether or not it'd be too broad if it were edited to ask for a bid critique (for example)

Comment: I leave that up to you... But I feel that one may be beyond recovery, as we aren't support for a website's features

Comment: Right. I guess my question should have been "Is a bid critique on- or off-topic?"

Comment: I think so, but how can we move it from being a support question for website abc? What about website xyz? Where would the line get drawn?

Comment: If it's a general bid critique question, then I wouldn't see any problem, not unless it involved a freelance site specifically